# Trying to avoid the JPA EntityListeners triggering for a OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Hellos people, I have my entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners(TaskInfoEntityListener.class)
public class TaskInfo extends Auditable {

    @Id
    private String taskId;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TaskComment> comments;
}
```

And when I run this piece of code

```
final TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo();
taskInfo.setTaskId("1234");

final TaskComment taskComment = new TaskComment();
taskComment.setComment("comment_1234");
taskInfo.setComments(Collections.singletonList(taskComment));

TaskInfo newTaskInfo = taskInfoRepository.save(taskInfo);
```

The EntityListener is run twice (the first one when the TaskInfo is saved and the second one when the comments are saved), but I want it once (only the first time). 
I´ve tried everything with the fetch and cascade in both sides but I can´t make it work. I also thought to put some kind of logic in the TaskInfoEntityListener in order to check whether or not the "comments" field changed but i don´t really like this solution.
What do you thing? Do you have a better approach or any other idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your EntityListener, try providing lifecycle listeners for each step, and see what gets called.  most likely you are getting called for different events. (maybe persist and update?)

```
@PrePersist
public void methodInvokedBeforePersist(TaskInfo ti) {
    System.out.println("persisting TaskInfo with id = " + ti.getTaskId());
}

@PostPersist
public void methodInvokedAfterPersist(TaskInfo ti) {
    System.out.println("Persisted TaskInfo with id = " + ti.getTaskId());
}

@PreUpdate
public void methodInvokedBeforeUpdate(TaskInfo ti) {
    System.out.println("Updating TaskInfo with id = " + ti.getTaskId());
}

@PostUpdate
public void methodInvokedAfterUpdate(TaskInfo ti) {
    System.out.println("Updated TaskInfo with id = " + ti.getTaskId());
}

@PreRemove
private void methodInvokedBeforeRemove(TaskInfo ti) {
    System.out.println("Removing TaskInfo with id = " + ti.getTaskId());
}

@PostRemove
public void methodInvokedAfterRemove(TaskInfo ti) {
    System.out.println("Removed TaskInfo with id = " + ti.getTaskId() );
}
```